# Using SQL Server TDE - Encryption 0 percent

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption

I'm using TDE for SQL Server. Querying certificate:

```
select database_name = d.name,
dek.encryptor_type,
cert_name = c.name
from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dek
left join sys.certificates c
on dek.encryptor_thumbprint = c.thumbprint
inner join sys.databases d
on dek.database_id = d.database_id;
```

Output:

```
database     encryptor        cert_name
tempdb      ASYMMETRIC KEY    NULL
TDE_Test    CERTIFICATE       TestZert3
```

Querying encryption status:

```
select db_name(database_id), encryption_state,   
percent_complete, key_algorithm, key_length
from sys.dm_database_encryption_keys
```

Output:

```
database  encrypt_state percent_complete key_algorithm
tempdb      3             0              AES 256 
TDE_Test    3             0               AES 256
```

Why is the complet_percent 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is the complect_percent 0?

Your database is already encrypted - `encrypt_state = 3 -- Encrypted.`

When the encryption is in progress, you will see the `percent_complete` value. When the database is encrypted, the `percent_complete` will be 0.

you can [refer to my script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheRockStarDBA/5f0d8f52649c045b072f/raw/d4b467d4a415a464f0443da84a8704459d1ec1ea/Get_TDE_Information.sql) for listing out the databases, encryption status along with other useful information.